# Explanation of GET Request in Arduino C++

Tags: http, arduino, get, arduino-c++

I'm using an Arduino to host a server with file transfer capabilities. My objective is to use HTTP to download / upload files to an SD card on the Arduino. I was having trouble implementing how the server handles a GET request so I found someone's code online. The code works and I can download text files but I have no idea how it works.

Here is the snippet that handles a GET request for a file:

```
client.println("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
client.println();
char file_buffer[16];
int avail;
while (avail = file.available()) {
  int to_read = min(avail, 16);
  if (to_read != file.read(file_buffer, to_read)) {
    break;
  }
  // uncomment the serial to debug (slow!)
  //Serial.write((char)c);
  client.write(file_buffer, to_read);
}
file.close();
```

Here is my train of thought:

1. While loop runs as long as [bytes are available to be read from the file.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FileAvailable)
2. Buffer length set to smallest of bytes available to read or max buffer size.
3. I'm not quite sure what the if statement is checking for.
4. Write available bytes from file buffer - **but where did we assign anything to the file buffer?**

Comment: "*where did we assign anything to the file buffer*". here: `file.read(file_buffer, to_read)`. That says read up to `to_read` bytes from `file` into `file_buffer`.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you! Unfortunately, I am still a little confused since that line is in an if statement. How is it actually executing the operation instead of checking for a condition?

Comment: It does both. That's just how C++ works. `if (X)` will evaluate `X` and then use the result as the condition for the `if`. The result of an assignment is the value that was assigned. No offense, but I do suggest you go through any C++ book or tutorial. This is really C++ language basic knowledge that should be learnt systematically before even attempting to write any code.